# Spring Boot Websocket on EKS Cluster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have websocket service embedded in Spring Boot Application.
The application is deployed on EKS Cluster and running on two pods and requests are routed to it via elb.
Same application has some rest endpoints exposed and whenever those endpoints are triggered some messages is published to a topic in websocket.

What happens when a client connect to pod1 websocket and rest endpoint of pod2 is triggered.

How should I handle it.

Since we are running only not running multi pod in dev environment could not really do much analysis and have not received any feedback from production where running multi pod cluster but curious to know what might have been happening.